# Flex security panel on Unix with wmode=transparent doesn't show up

Tags: flash, apache-flex, unix, browser, webcam

When using a Flash applet accessing the webcam and setting wmode=transparent, the security panel asking for the permission to access the webcam doesn't show up on Unix systems (like Mac or Linux). Is there a trick or work-around for this issue?

Things I've tried:

Setting the security panel explicitly via `Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.CAMERA)` doesn't work, right-clicking on the applet won't be possible either. Another unsuccessful try was to have two applets access the webcam simultaneously - one with and one without wmode=transparent. But the webcam permission doesn't seem to affect the other Flash applets on the same page.

The only thing I came up with is sending the user to [the Adobe website security panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html) and letting them activate their webcam there. Or load a non-transparent Flash applet in advance, asking to check the box "allow always", then loading the transparent one. I'm not happy with either of them.

The behaviour occurs on any browser.

Comment: did you try making the background alpha of your application 1.0 and giving it a colour, for the time the security panel is supposed to be visible.This may work.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a workaround than a real solution, but it is doable.

A couple of different solutions

Case #1
How about creating a separate div layer and a separate SWF, showing it as wmod window, which should show the Dialog box, and then once the user has provided explicit permissions on the dialog box, you make a call to a JavaScript function that removes that first layer, brings in a second layer where you have the main SWF in your transparent mode.

Case #2
Dirty, but you could show an iframe that shows that settings page right below your SWF, and that way you aren't making your users to go out to a new page.

I realize neither of these are actual solutions, but hopefully they can serve as temporary workarounds until there is a permanent fix to it.

Comment: Neither of these solutions worked. However, the latest Flash version (11) seems to fix many issues with webcam and linux. Was about time.